# JQuery function is not working after URL Rewriting

Tags: asp.net

Refer to my this question: [Page not redirecting properly, URL rewriting (Asp.NET)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5403247/page-not-redirecting-properly-url-rewriting-asp-net)

Which is resolved except one thing.

Though I have put the code to eliminate post back for .jpg and other file extension, JQuery at the web page is not working.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jquery.js"></script>
```

I have written it like the above. I have tried to change the path like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/JS/jquery.js"></script>
```

but no luck.

Any suggestion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src= "<%=ResolveUrl("~/JS/jquery.js")%>" ></script>
```

Comment: Now it is working fine. and also my issue with Stackoverflow javascript error is also resolved.

Answer (score 1):

you first check if the string contains  /web/

```
if (app.Request.RawUrl.ToLower().Contains("/web/"))
```

and your .js file doesn't contain /web/

so either put the js file in the web folder, or check for the string to contain /js/ as well...

```
 if (app.Request.RawUrl.ToLower().Contains("/web/") ||  if (app.Request.RawUrl.ToLower().Contains("/js/")))
```